# Objective C: NSRange location value is not what it should be

Tags: objective-c

I have this method which extracts data from NSData at a specific pointer. The method only extracts a certain amount of bytes, in this case it is 4 bytes as I return a uint32.

I pass in a pointer (int start) which is used to create the location for an NSRange, the length of the range is the size of a uint32, which creates the range as 4 bytes long.

This works perfectly fine, until the pointer gets to 2147483648. When it gets to this value, the range is not created with 2147483648 for the location value instead it is created as 18446744071562067968 which is out of bounds for the data, and causes an exception to occur halting my program which stops it from reading the rest of the data.

I have no idea what is causing it do what its doing, the start value is the correct value when it is passed into the method, but it changes when the range is created. It does not happen for any of the previous pointer values.

Have I done something silly in my code? Or is it a different problem? Help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
    - (uint32)getUINT32ValueFromData:(NSData *)rawData pointer:(int)start {
        uint32 value;
        NSRange range;

        int length = sizeof(uint32);
        NSUInteger dataLength = rawData.length;

        NSData *currentData;

        NSUInteger remainingBytes = dataLength - start;

        if (remainingBytes > length) {
             range.location = start;
             range.length = length;
             //should be 2147483648, location in range is showing  18446744071562067968 which is out of bounds...
             currentData = [rawData subdataWithRange:range];

             uint32 hostData = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(*(const uint32 *)[currentData bytes]);

             value = hostData;

            pointer = start + length;
          }
          else
          {
          NSLog(@"Data Length Exceeded!");
          }

          return value;
      }
```

Comment: Try changing `start` from `int` to `NSUInteger`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems to be an 32/64 bit and signed/unsigned mismatch issue.

You're using three different types

- `int` is a 32 bit signed type
- `uint32` is a 32 bit unsigned type
- `NSUInteger` is a 32/64 bit unsigned type depending on the processor architecture.

`unit32` for the value is fine, but you should use `NSUInteger` for the offset into the `NSData` object.

Comment: And that type should be `NSUInteger`, allowing the addressing of 4GB of data under 32-bit architectures.

Comment: for still more clarity ;-)

Comment: Thank you all for responding. It is working now, I changed the `start` value from an `int` to an `NSUInteger`.

Comment: @bradleyjgray Don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions.